# iruby no bash commands possible in jupyter notebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, iruby

I am using iruby in my jupyter notebook and the kernel is working as expected and accepting all kind of ruby syntax

Unfortunately the %%bash command leads to an error. So no console commands are usable in my notebook. If i switch back to the basic python kernel, the %%bash commands are working as expected.

How can i achieve that the bash commands are working in the iruby kernel? Is there something I forgot to install or set up?

I use following settings in Ubuntu 20.04:

I also use rvm to manage my ruby version.

Basic setup

```
sudo apt install python3-pip python3-dev
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv
pip install jupyter
```

Installing iruby

```
gem install ffi-rzmq
gem install iruby --pre
iruby register --force
```

setup and start

```
rvm use ruby-2.7.2
mkdir ~/ruby_notebook

virtualenv ~/ruby_notebook/ruby_env
source ~/ruby_notebook/ruby_env/bin/activate

jupyter notebook --notebook-dir ~/ruby_notebook
```

But following error occurs:
[image]

Any ideas how to solve this issue at all so that I can use bash commands?

*======== UPDATE and Solution ======*

Thanks to engineersmnky I found the solution:

like in python notebook I want to achieve following output:

[image: python bash command]

with the command `%x(ls -la)` I get an execution but the output looks different like

[image]

So to get a correct output I added following:

```
%x(ls -la).each_line(chomp: true){|s| p s}
```

which comes close to the output but followed by an exection strinfg output in the notebook.

[image]

So my **final solution**, also to make the execution command less complicated I am using a method in the beginning of my notebook now.

```
def execute_console(input)
  %x(#{input}).each_line(chomp: true){|s| p s}
  return nil
end
```

This way I can execute special command sin my notebook using rails like

```
rails routes
```

in

```
execute_console('rails routes')
```

and the output is like expected without any string output.

[image]

Syntax errors are printed out as expected as well.

Comment: The following should also work `require 'pp'; pp(%x(ls -la)); nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute commands at a system level you can use any of the following: [`Kernel#system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Kernel.html#method-i-system), `%x` (see below for more about percent strings), or [Kernel#`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Kernel.html#method-i-60) ("back ticks")

```
system('pwd')
%x(pwd) 
`pwd`
```

These will all run in process and return the output as a String.

If you want the commands to run in a separate process you can use other options such as `IO.popen` or `fork { exec('pwd') }` ( if supported by the OS)

**TL;DR Why the error is occurring**

Now to explain your actual error and why it is occurring.

This line is but `%%bash` is being interpreted by ruby and it is looking for a closing `%`.
`%` is another way of creating a string literal (called a ["Percent String"](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings)).

The interesting part about this syntax is it does not  really have a defined delimiter. (essentially most non-alphanumerics can open and close)

```
%{bash}
#=> "bash" 
%(bash)
#=> "bash"
%|bash| 
#=> "bash"
```

The last line of the docs states

> If you are using “(”, “[”, “{”, “<” you must close it with “)”, “]”, “}”, “>” respectively. You may use most other non-alphanumeric characters for percent string delimiters such as “%”, “|”, “^”, etc.

In your case `%` is being used as the delimiter: e.g.

```
%%bash%
#=> "bash"
```

but since there is no closing `%` this is being interpreted as:

```
%%bash
pwd 
--EOF--
```

Thus the error you are receiving because the `String` (`"bash\npwd`) is unterminated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but now I have a follow up questions. The output of the command %x(ls -ls)  is a raw string and e.g. linebreaks (/n) are not working. If I compare this again with the behavior of with python notebook  %%bash ls -la (or !ls -la) which has  a well formatted output. Under ruby  it is only am awful long string and not really a  readable output like in a terminal. Is there another command to get a nicer string output?

Comment: @F.M. not sure what you mean. `%x(ls -ls).each_line(chomp: true).to_a` returns an `Array` of each line if that is what you are asking for. so `puts %x(ls -ls).each_line(chomp: true).to_a` will "view" very much like the terminal would but the return value for thsi line will be `nil`